# What is difference between /dev/vcs, /dev/vcsu and /dev/vcsa? Why are there so many of them?

Tags: command-line, tty, devices, virtual-console

I know about vcs and vcsa by reading [this](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man4/vcs.4.html) but I find nothing regarding vcsu.

Answer (score 2):

The `u` stands for unicode.

`/dev/vcs*` devices only show an [ansi](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extended_ASCII) representation of the screen content, if you want to use [unicode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unicode_input) you need to set this up with the correct code page for the screen device.

As of kernel version 4.19 each `/dev/vcs*` also has a `/dev/vcsu*` that allows for reading unicode data from the screen device.